# Zabbix server set value from agent failed: ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out

Tags: zabbix

We are using Zabbix 4.0 LTS server which is running on **master**. But the agents are of 1.6 version and running on **client** server.
Agents are listening on port 8077 of **client** server. When we are configuring host (as client) in Zabbix server where IP is the client's IP and port is 8077, they will successfully connect. But I need to know whether some of the applications are running on the client server or not.
Eg. need to know whether tomcat is running on port 8080 on client server through Zabbix.
So we are adding host with client IP and mentioned port 8080 where Tomcat is running (instead of 8077) in Zabbix host configuration. But in this scenario it is giving error

Get value from agent failed: ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out

But when I telnet from Master to Client, it is working fine on the port 8080.
The same feature is working fine in Zabbix 2.2 LTS version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YafNa.png)

Answer (score 1):

On port 8080, it is not a Zabbix agent that responds for you.
Instead, add the host with the correct agent port and use either [agent item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) like `net.tcp.port` and `net.tcp.service`, or [simple check](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks) like `net.tcp.service`.

Note that it is unlikely agent communication on Tomcat port worked in any version of Zabbix.